# BVP eigenvalue problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, mathematical-physics

I am working on the following problem and I am completely stuck:

Show that the eigenvalue problem
$$
-u''+4\pi^{2}\int_{0}^{1} u(x)\,dx=\lambda\,u
$$
with $u(0)=u(1)$ and $u'(0)=u'(1)$ has $\lambda=4\pi^2$ an eigenvalue of multiplicity $3$. I don't how to deal with the integral term. No solutions please but any hint will be much appreciated.

Comment: what happens if you substitute $u_n = \sin(2n+1)x, n$ an integer? $(2n+1)^2 + {8\pi \over (2n+1)} = \lambda_n $

Comment: where is the guess for un coming from?

Comment: i think you can try $\cos(n\pi x), \sin(n \pi x)$ too. they all satisfy the periodic boundary conditions.